# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Laravel Application)

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5.4

I'm having this error in my laravel application.

these are the tables:

**Post**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
});
```

**Categories**

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Post_Category**

```
Schema::create('post_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->unique()->nullable();
       $table->integer('cat_id')->unsigned()->unique()->nullable();
       $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Foreign Keys**

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->foreign('id')->references('post_id')->on('post_category')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreign('id')->references('cat_id')->on('post_category')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Here my models**

```
class Categorie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\PostCategory');
    }
}
```

...

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function author() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function featuredImage() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Media', 'media_id');
    }

    public function categories() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\PostCategory');
    }
}
```

...

```
class PostCategory extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'post_category';
}
```

**Here the controllers**

Store Category:

```
public function store(StoreCategory $request)
    {
        $category = new Categorie;
        $category->name = $request->input('name');
        $category->save();

        return redirect('/admin/categories')->with('status', 'New category created!');
    }
```

Store post

```
public function store(StorePost $request)
    {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->content = $request->input('content');
        $post->media_id = $request->input('media_id');
        $post->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/admin/posts')->with('status', 'New post created!');
    }
```

Having this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`the_film_corner`.`tfc_categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `tfc_post_category` (`cat_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `tfc_categories` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (News, 2017-02-26 14:51:15, 2017-02-26 14:51:15))

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add the foreign keys in the wrong table:

```
Schema::table('post_category', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('post')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Then...

```
class Categorie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');

     // Or more specifically
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_category', 'id', 'post_id');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function categories() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');

      // Or more specifically
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_category', 'id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

You can find more information following the official guide for Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Thanks Samuele for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The error says everything. With this setup, before you insert a row into `tfc_categories`, the value for the column `id` has to exist in the column `cat_id` of the table `tfc_post_category`. If not, you violate the constraint mentioned in the failure message.

But I rather guess you wanted one column to reference the other vice versa.

Comment: Explaining the theory by itself is not very useful, a description of a solution would help your answer tremendously. I read your explanation and I find it very hard to follow along because the questioner has quite a bit of code, and this doesn't cite an answer to the problem, just an explanation of what is going on. Explaining the theory is very useful, don't get me wrong, but a walk through example is much more helpful, not only for the questioner but future viewers of the problem.

Comment: The Solution, obviously, would be to add a record to `tfc_post_category` with the respective `id` first.

Comment: No not obviously, if it was obvious, s/he wouldn't be asking a question about it. You just reiterated the error and you barely expanded on what it meant. The Questioner lists out everything in detail because he is running into an error and it is not "obvious" what the solution is.

Comment: Allow me to cite myself: "_... before you insert a row into `tfc_categories`, the value for the column `id` has to exist in the column `cat_id` of the table `tfc_post_category`_". That's the proposed solution.